# how to generate token expire itself after 24 hours?

Tags: django, token

I am trying to create a better way to generate tokens that expire itself after 24 hours, but I want to test it with 1-minute timing that it is really doing the job. I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but if not help me

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six
from django.utils.crypto import constant_time_compare
from django.utils.http import base36_to_int


class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )

    def check_token(self, user, token):
        # This is a copy and clean of the super check_token code removing what is not required in this case
        if not (user and token):
            return False
        try:
            ts_b36, _ = token.split("-")
            ts = base36_to_int(ts_b36)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        if (self._num_days(self._today()) - ts) > 1: # 1 day = 24 hours 
            return False
        return True

account_activation_token = AccountActivationTokenGenerator()
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you are creating a standard JWT token or similar token using the generator, these tokens are stored as session cookies in the browser. You can set the expiry of these cookies. You store the token in session by

```
request.session['token']=token
```

and then set expiry by

```
request.session.set_expiry(300) #this means 300 seconds or 5 minutes
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? @Aron-Imperial